# Git: sychronize files with unmanaged folder

Tags: git, directory, unmanaged, synchronize

I got 2 folders with the same files.

- gitprojects/npm_project
- gitprojects/projectA/node_modules/npm_project

The first folder is managed with git, the 2nd one is not.
I am editing the files in the 2nd folder. It's easier to work there.

After finishing work, I want to copy the changed files to the 1st folder.
I could just use `cp -R`. But that might be not good, I don't want to copy all files, and it can be dangerous, I could overwrite file changes.

Does `git` provide a good feature, comparing a folder with an unmanaged one, and merge them?

Comment: Can't you just use delete 2nd location and clone it from 1st location? You can have as many local copies of a repo as you like. That would give you all the power of git.

Comment: The 2nd location is installed with `npm install`, it's easier for me to edit there while it's required by projectA, and I need to make changes on both projects.

Comment: There is nothing provided by git to do what you want. What you want is git. The alternative of doing stuff manually (like copying, merging, etc.) can be automated by using git. It is likely that a more useful solution would be to figure out what behaviours are provided by `npm install` that aren't provided by `git clone`, and providing those somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have done a commit on the contents of folder 1 (`gitprojects/npm_project`). Since folder 1 is now fully managed by Git (i.e., you can return to prior states simply by using Git commands), you can copy all the files from folder 2 to folder 1 -- there is no need to worry about files you don't want copied since you can just remove them from folder 1 after the copy.

With all files from folder 2 copied to folder 1, simply use `git status` and `git diff` to see your changes from folder 2.

**Note**: you'll find in the long run that maintaining all your source in version control is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a better idea:

I delete all files in folder 2 using `rm -rf`, after the `npm install`, and create a symbolic link to folder 1:

```
cd gitprojects/projectA
npm install
code node_modules
rm -rf npm_project
ln -s /full/path/to/gitprojects/npm_project npm_project
```